# NodeJs Restify SQLServer TypeScript - IIS - Impossible mission?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, typescript, iis, restify

I'd like to start a Rest API project using NodeJS with Restify, but, the environment is Windows (not cloud, not Azure, AWS etc, but local server), with IIS and to make it hardest, with SQLServer. Oh, almost forgot, using Typescript.

Is it a impossible mission?

Does anybody has some guides, docs whatever?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

> I'd like to start a Rest API project using NodeJS with Restify, but, the environment is Windows (not cloud, not Azure, AWS etc, but local server), with IIS and to make it hardest, with SQLServer. Oh, almost forgot, using Typescript.
>   Is it a impossible mission?
>   Does anybody has some guides, docs whatever?

As far as I know, we could host node.js application on IIS. This is not related with typescript or else.  If you could publish  the node.js to a deployment file.  Then we could try to use iisnode to achieve this requirement.

For more details, I suggest you could refer to this article to know how install it and publish the node.js application to IIS.

Link:
https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode

Comment: I already read this, but, is an old stuff, is about IIS7, now, we are with Win2016 Src with IIS 10, is still working yet?

Comment: Yes, it works well with IIS10. Details, you could see this github issue [description](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/590).